Unpredictable Collapse/Expand Behavior in UICollectionViewListCell Implementation
I implemented collapse/expand functionality using UICollectionViewListCell and a Diffable Data Source.
However, the resulting behavior is unpredictable. When a row is tapped, it should expand while other rows collapse, but this isn't happening consistently. Please refer to the video below for further context.

This is my source code :
ViewController.swift
import UIKit

enum Section : Codable {
    case note
}

extension UIView {
    static func getUINib() -> UINib {
        return UINib(nibName: String(describing: self), bundle: nil)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let strings = [
        "Helo world",
        "Good bye world",
        "Hotdog",
        "Egg",
        "The word collapse has multiple meanings, including:",
        "A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. ",
        "short text"
        
    ]
    
    private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
    
    lazy var cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<DemoListCell, String>(cellNib: DemoListCell.getUINib()) { [weak self] (demoListCell, indexPath, string) in
        
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        if indexPath == self.selectedIndexPath {
            print(">>>> expand - \(string)")
            demoListCell.expand()
        } else {
            print(">>>> collapse - \(string)")
            demoListCell.collapse()
        }
        demoListCell.label.text = string
    }
    
    private typealias DataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, String>
    private typealias Snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, String>

    private var dataSource: DataSource!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layoutConfig()
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        
        dataSource = makeDataSource()
        
        var snapshot = Snapshot()
        snapshot.appendSections([.note])
        snapshot.appendItems(strings, toSection: .note)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }

    private func layoutConfig() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { section, layoutEnvironment in
            var config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)

            config.headerMode = .none
            config.footerMode = .none
            config.showsSeparators = true
            config.headerTopPadding = 0
            
            config.backgroundColor = nil
            
            let layoutSection = NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: config, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
            
            return layoutSection
        }
        
        return layout
    }
    
    private func makeDataSource() -> DataSource {
        let cellRegistration = self.cellRegistration
        
        let dataSource = DataSource(
            collectionView: collectionView,
            cellProvider: { [weak self] (collectionView, indexPath, item) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
                guard let self = self else { return nil }
                
                return collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(
                    using: cellRegistration,
                    for: indexPath,
                    item: item
                )
            }
        )
        
        return dataSource
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        
        var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
        
        snapshot.reconfigureItems(snapshot.itemIdentifiers)

        print(">>>> === apply ===")
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true) {
            collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
        
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}

DemoListCell.swift
class DemoListCell: UICollectionViewListCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var extraView: UIView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func expand() {
        extraView.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func collapse() {
        extraView.isHidden = true
    }
}

Here is the complete workable source code - https://github.com/yccheok/expand-collapse
Do you have any idea how I can fix this? Thanks.

It looks like you use many empty strings for this example. Could it be that the engine can't say the difference between two rows, because they all essentially equal ("" == "")?

I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. None of the rows contain empty strings, and each string is intentionally unique. Could you explain further? Thanks!

I mean the expanded area (red in your example). I assumed it contains empty strings. If I'm wrong, me guess is useless ofc.

Instead of show/hide the view use two different cell for this case like below.
class ExpandCell: UICollectionViewListCell {
    private var label: UILabel!
    private var imageView: UIImageView!
    private var extraView: UIView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setData(_ title: String) {
        label.text = title
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        
        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        
        extraView = UIView()
        extraView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        extraView.backgroundColor = .red
        contentView.addSubview(extraView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: label.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.centerYAnchor),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18),
            
            extraView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            extraView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            extraView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor),
            extraView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            extraView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])
    }
}

class CollapseCell: UICollectionViewListCell {
    private var label: UILabel!
    private var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func setData(_ title: String) {
        label.text = title
    }
    
    private func setup() {
        label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        
        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            
            imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: label.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18),
            imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 18)
        ])
    }
}

enum Section : Codable {
    case note
}

struct Item: Hashable {
    let text: String
    var isExpanded: Bool
}

private typealias DataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Item>
private typealias Snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    private var items: [Item] = [
        .init(text: "Hello world", isExpanded: false),
        .init(text: "Good bye world", isExpanded: false),
        .init(text: "Hotdog", isExpanded: false),
        .init(text: "Egg", isExpanded: false),
        .init(text: "The word collapse has multiple meanings, including:", isExpanded: false),
        .init(text: "A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. A very loooooong text. ", isExpanded: false),
        .init(text: "short text", isExpanded: false)
    ]
    
    private var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
    
    lazy var collapseCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<CollapseCell, Item> { cell, _, item in
        cell.setData(item.text)
    }
    
    lazy var expandCellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<ExpandCell, Item> { cell, _, item in
        cell.setData(item.text)
    }
    
    private var dataSource: DataSource!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layoutConfig()
        collectionView.delegate = self
        dataSource = makeDataSource()
        updateDataSource()
    }
    
    private func layoutConfig() -> UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout {
        UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { section, layoutEnvironment in
            var config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
            config.headerMode = .none
            config.footerMode = .none
            config.showsSeparators = true
            config.headerTopPadding = 0
            config.backgroundColor = nil
            
            return NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(
                using: config,
                layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment
            )
        }
    }
    
    private func makeDataSource() -> DataSource {
        let collapseCellRegistration = self.collapseCellRegistration
        let expandCellRegistration = self.expandCellRegistration
        
        return DataSource(
            collectionView: collectionView,
            cellProvider: { collectionView, indexPath, item in
                if item.isExpanded {
                    collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(
                        using: expandCellRegistration,
                        for: indexPath,
                        item: item
                    )
                } else {
                    collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(
                        using: collapseCellRegistration,
                        for: indexPath,
                        item: item
                    )
                }
            }
        )
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        items[indexPath.row].isExpanded = !items[indexPath.row].isExpanded
        if let selectedIndexPath = selectedIndexPath, selectedIndexPath != indexPath {
            items[selectedIndexPath.row].isExpanded = false
        }
        
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        updateDataSource()
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    
    func updateDataSource() {
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
        snapshot.appendSections([.note])
        snapshot.appendItems(items, toSection: .note)
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true)
    }
}

